# C# HttpRequest User-Agent HEader - something that does not reflect a browser or a browser library

Tags: c#, httprequest, user-agent

Good day!
I am trying to find out which User-Agent can be used in the HttpRequest if I have this information:

> C# HttpRequest User-Agent Header must be something that does not
> reflect a browser or a browser library.

Usually, we use Browser as a User-Agent, not here.
Did you have similar situation maybe?

C# HttpRequest User-Agent Header must be something that does not reflect a browser or a browser library. What it can be?

Comment: The User-Agent header can be set to whatever you would like it to be set to. It is just a string.

Comment: User agent sniffing is common in websites, though less common than it used to be. If you do not specify a user agent or it doesn’t recognize the user agent, you may be sent a very low quality page made for old browsers. At the very least you should have the mozilla/5.0 part, which you can read up on here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent